# Remove the dependency of a program from certain DLL

Tags: c, dll

I'm writing an application in C, which uses pcre3.dll for regular expression.

The problem is that the program requires pcre3.dll in every client computer I'm trying to run the program on.

How can I remove the dependency of my application from pcre3.dll ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Deploying C app that uses the PCRE library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343859/deploying-c-app-that-uses-the-pcre-library)

Comment: You can get the static lib [here](http://www.psyon.org/projects/pcre-win32/), the files ending with `-static.zip`.

Comment: Not a dupe IMO: the other question is targeted at *nix and also  does not offer any specific instructions.

Comment: +1 to @HostileFork, IMO it's a duplicate, only the platform is different.

Comment: @Jon The theory (though not necessarily an effective practice) is that noticing commonality in questions will lead them to link together.  This draws attention to the older question so it gets brought up to date wiki-style, and becomes an even better resource instead of suffering the dreaded web rot.  Conventions still evolving, though... http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/dr-strangedupe-or-how-i-learned-to-stop-worrying-and-love-duplication/

Answer (score 3):

You need to link to pcre3 statically instead of dynamically as you do now.

If you compile pcre from source, then as the NON-UNIX-USE file states:

> LINKING PROGRAMS IN WINDOWS ENVIRONMENTS
>
> If you want to statically link a program against a PCRE library in the
>   form of a non-dll .a file, you must define PCRE_STATIC before
>   including pcre.h or pcrecpp.h, otherwise the pcre_malloc() and
>   pcre_free() exported functions will be declared __declspec(dllimport),
>   with unwanted results.

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon, although I used the static library Andre gave in the comment above.